# Programmatically send emails pass customer vars

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on the custom e-mail sending script which will get customers details and pass them into e-mail template.

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
        //send feedback
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('e-mail templaet code');         

        $emailTemplateVariables = array();
        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName('Sender name');
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('sender@example.com');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject("email subject");
        $emailTemplate->send('mail@example.com','Some name Some surname', $emailTemplateVariables);
}
```

Is there any way so I can pass all vars from $customer to `$emailTemplateVariables` ?

And those vars will be used as `{{var customer.email}}` in the e-mail template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an array with a key value pair like below:

```
array("email"=>"xxx@example.com")
```

and assign this array to your 
`$emailTemplateVariables['customer']=array("email"=>"xxx@example.com")` variable.

Now you will be able to get the customer email value on `template{{var customer.email}}`